# Using rmate with multiple Users to connect to the same server (with VS Code remote) - how to use a socket? Or other ideas?

Tags: python, sockets, server, visual-studio-code, textmate

I am trying to set up VS Code remote with rmate (https://pypi.org/project/rmate/ i.e. this is the content I copied and turned into an executable file https://raw.githubusercontent.com/sclukey/rmate-python/master/bin/rmate) to edit files on a server that a few people on my team would potentially access at the same time.

I am using Host: 127.0.0.1 and Port: 52698 to connect to the remote server. It all works perfectly until a second person tries to connect as well in which case typing "rmate file.py" opens it on the person's computer who logged in first - and that is expected since we are using the same host and port - but it's not what I want obviously, everyone should have their own connection and only be able to open a file in their own vs code editor.

I tried to change the localhost and the port. But it is not very convenient i.e. who uses which one? how do I keep track of that? seems rather bad from a long term perspective - it would be ok if we could use employee IDs but since the localhost and port only work in certain ranges, that is not feasible. Also, in order to change the port to be used, I have to go edit the rmate file and change the port manually so everyone would need to reference a different rmate file (small problem, but we currently use the same rmate file).

What I saw is that some other versions of rmate use a socket (https://github.com/textmate/rmate/pull/38) so I tried that and couldn't get it to work either (file opening on coworkers computer persists) - one reason is that I did not understand how they do it, just that it is possible and second part is that I am not sure if the python rmate version is even setup for that.

I used the following config settings to try to use a socket instead:

Host test

```
Port 22

User <my username>

IdentityFile ~/.ssh/<ssh file>

HostName <hostname>

RemoteForward 52698 127.0.0.1:52698

ControlMaster auto

ControlPath ~/.ssh/socket-%r@%h:%pOA
```

The last two lines are an attempt to use a socket. There is no file in the .ssh folder that has anything to do with a socket - this is just something I found online, so it might be completely useless, but it does still log me in correctly and I noticed that I can no longer log in from two different command lines if I use this host to ssh.

Note: I don't know much about sockets - I just know theoretically what they do when someone visits a website.

Comment: A couple external answers: [on SuperUser](https://superuser.com/questions/1318523/connecting-to-ubuntu-runnning-rmate-via-multiple-machines-on-the-same-network) and [on GitHub](https://github.com/randy3k/remote-atom/issues/37), both summarized nicely in [this tutorial](https://acarril.github.io/posts/ssh-sripts-st3#multiple-users-on-same-server).  Basically they recommend hard-coding a different port for each user. :-/ It'd be nice there was some more automatic way of negotiating a port.  Even when I, (the same user) run multiple ssh to a remote server, it may say the port is already in use.